# Cannot fetch data from database by error : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at DisasterSource.showDisaster

Tags: json

I'm new to hosting my project, so I've connected to database, but problem showed up.

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at DisasterSource.showDisaster
```

Here's my code:

```
class DisasterSource {
  static async showDisaster() {
    const response = await fetch('./src/scripts/data/filtered-data.php');
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson.data;
  }
}

export default DisasterSource;
```

In additional, I bring my.php file:

```
<?php
require '../../../koneksi.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM v_disasterlogs_all";

  $response = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);

  if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) > 0) {
    $result = array();

    $days= date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-5 days'));

      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response))
      {
        if ( $row['eventdate'] > $days) {
          $result[] = $row;
        }
      }
      $status = "1";
      $message = "success";
      echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status, 'message'=>$message, 'data' => $result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      mysqli_close($conn);
  } else {
    $status = "0";
    $message = "error";
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status, 'message'=>$message), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  }

?>
```

Everything works fine except this data, it wont be fetched from database. Any solution?

Comment: your response from php file seems to be returning string or some other data. Your php is not returnung any json data type.

Comment: so I should add Content-type header? @AlwaysHelping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, it was caused by non-ascii char.

Fix by adding this:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

or

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string);
```